# C++ 2D array index compare

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I need help in a C++ for a school task.
I don't really know where the error is.
It seems like it skips the first row.

### **I should compare the highest value with an other row's avarage value.**

Task:
In the first row of the standard input there are the count of the cities (1≤N≤1000) and the count of days (1≤M≤1000). In the following N row there are the daily forecast M temperature values (-50≤Hi,j≤50).
In the standard output's first row, you have to write the city number, which maximal forecast has to be lower than some other city's avarage temperature! If there is none you should write -1!

Example:
Input

```
3 5
11 11 11 11 20
18 16 12 16 20
10 15 12 10 10
```

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int N, M;
    cin >> N;
    cin >> M;

    int homerseklet[N][M];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            cin >> homerseklet[i][j];
        }
    }

    int maxh[N] = {0}, osszh[N] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        maxh[i] = homerseklet[i][0];
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            osszh[i] = osszh[i] + homerseklet[i][j];
            if (homerseklet[i][j] > maxh[i])
            {
                maxh[i] = homerseklet[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    int atlag[N] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        atlag[i] = osszh[i] / M;
    }

    bool van = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (i != j && maxh[i] < atlag[j])
            {
                if (van = true)
                {
                    cout << i + 1 << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (!van)
    {
        cout << -1 << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int homerseklet[N][M]` is not a valid c++, you should use dynamic allocation for runtime size dependent arrays

Comment: [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) `std::vector<std::vector<int>> homerseklet(N, std::vector<int>(M)); std::vector<int> osszes(N, 0);` instead of `int homerseklet[N][M], osszes[N] = {0};`

Comment: Your code snippet is C++ code. It does not compile with a C compiler. Please remove the C tag.

Comment: In practice, `atlag` should memorize the maximum average temperature

Comment: Why do you think there is an error? I get the expected output with the given input: https://wandbox.org/permlink/JSkbUUFBAZsgKMzu

Comment: @ThomasSablik It may work here because the maximum average temperature corresponds to the last row in this example

Comment: @Damien A [mcve] should contain an example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I did not say the contrary :)

Comment: @Damien Of course, you are right, but I don't like if people dump their code with "It doesn't work. Please fix it" without any effort. At least OP should provide problematic input and describe the problem.

Comment: In the loop `for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        aveh = sumh[i]/M;
    }` you are repeatedly setting `aveh` but the value is overwritten in the next loop iteration and only the last value is stored in the variable. The loop is the same as `aveh = sumh[N-1]/M;`

Comment: In your example you define a variable `summh` but you use a variable `sumh`. Please provide actual code that you compiled and tested.

Comment: It was pretty much solved. Thank you for your help!